# Iterate Error in DataLoader module 'numpy' has no attribute 'expand_dim'

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

I want to iterate throw the trainloader but I face this problem, Any help in this error .

```
for imgs, mask in trainloader:
    print(imags.shape)
    print(masks.shape)
    break
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-22799795e016> in <module>()
----> 1 for imgs, mask in trainloader:
      2     print(imags.shape)
      3     print(masks.shape)
      4     break

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py in __getattr__(attr)
    312 
    313             raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
--> 314                                  "{!r}".format(__name__, attr))
    315 
    316         def __dir__():

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'expand_dim'
```